# SingleEmailMessage ToAddresses + CcAddresses Limit?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

The requirement is I want to deactivate users  on weekly basis if they are not using salesforce licence and once users deactivate i have to send an email alert(single email) to users and their respective managers.I know with the help of automation(Process Builder or Workflow rule) i can send an email alert to users and their managers but the requirement is I have to put their manager in CC.I have referred no of documents and found that I can not put email address in CC via automation process.
But with the help of apex it is possible(SingleEmailMessage) but then I have read another article on [Email Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm).

about email limits and salesforce has mentioned that Max 100 recipients i can put in TO field and 25 in CC.
What would happen if I want to send an email to 100 users(recipient)& their respective managers(100)?
will it hit email limit?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation itself is pretty clear:

> - You can specify up to 100 recipients for the To field and up to 25 recipients for the CC and BCC fields in each SingleEmailMessage.

So the absolute maximum number of recipients for one `SingleEmailMessage` is 150, and that would be using all 25 available for `CC` and `BCC`.

Comment: Would you like to recommend any viable workaround,if any?